# How to fetch data from another app Django

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I'm creating a quiz project using Django with MongoEngine. Multiple Choice Questions and quiz are two separated apps. I want to fetch multiple choice in quiz based on m_id (unique number for each multiple choice). I'm a beginner and need a little help. How can i achieve this
**MCQS Model**

```
from django_mongoengine import Document, EmbeddedDocument, fields
class multichoice(Document):
    m_id = fields.IntField(min_value=1, verbose_name='MCQ Id')
    m_title = fields.StringField(primary_key=True, max_length=255, verbose_name='Title')
    m_question = fields.StringField(verbose_name='Question')
    m_alternatives = fields.ListField(fields.StringField(),verbose_name='Alternatives')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.m_title
```

**Quiz Model**

```
from django_mongoengine import Document, EmbeddedDocument, fields
from mcqs.models import *
class quiz(Document):
    q_id = fields.IntField(min_value=1, verbose_name='Quiz ID')
    q_title = fields.StringField(primary_key=True, max_length=255, verbose_name='Title')
    q_s_description = fields.StringField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Description')
    q_questions = fields.ListField(fields.IntField(), verbose_name='Question Numbers', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.q_title
```

**MCQ Views**

```
def view_multichoice(request, m_id):
    get_md = multichoice.objects(m_question_number = m_id)
    return render(request, 'mcqs/mcq.html', {'get_md':get_md})
```

**Quiz Views**

```
def view_quiz(request, q_id):
    get_q = quiz.objects(q_id = q_id)
    return render(request, 'quiz/quiz.html', {'get_q':get_q})
```

Current Result
[image: Current Result]
Expected Result
[image: Expected Result]

**EDIT 1**
**Quiz Views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
from mcqs.models import *
def view_quiz(request, q_id):

    quiz_object = quiz.objects(q_id=q_id)[0]
    multichoice_objects = [multichoice.objects(m_id=id) for id in quiz_object.q_questions]
    get_q = [objects[0].m_question for objects in multichoice_objects if objects]
    return render(request, 'quiz/quiz.html', {'get_q':get_q})
```

**Quiz Template**

```
{{ get_q }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the question documents as it is. What you should be doing is, fetch the multichoice documents corresponding to the question ids, and then get the question field from each of those documents.

Change the second line in quiz views to this:

```
# Get the question document corresponding to given id
# objects method returns a list. Get the first one out of it. 
# Here, I've assumed there's exactly 1 quiz document per ID. Handle the edge cases

quiz_object = quiz.objects(q_id = q_id)[0] 

# Get the multiple choice documents corresponding to the ids in q_questions list
# Remember that objects method returns a list. Hence this is a list of lists
 
multichoice_objects = [multichoice.objects(m_id=id) for id in quiz_object.q_questions]

# Get the actual questions from the multichoice documents

get_q = [objects[0].m_question for objects in multichoice_objects if objects]
```

Ideally, you should be making multichoice as an EmbeddedDocument and the `q_questions` field in quiz model as EmbeddedDocumentListField. But the drawback here will be, you can't query EmbeddedDocuments independently. So you wont be able to do `multichoice.objects(m_question_number=m_id)`.

You can read more about EmbeddedDocuments [here](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument)

Comment: I'm getting an empty list.

Comment: Code is in EDIT 1

Comment: It's working fine. There was a program in Database. Thanks for the help